# How can I ask in stack that after updating CIFS samba client stopped working?

Tags: raspbian, apt, samba, cifs

after "apt dist-upgrade" cifs stopped working.

When working I had:

```
:$ modinfo cifs
...
version:        2.40
...
```

Now (didnt working):

```
:$ modinfo cifs
...
version:        2.45
...
```

I tried mounting with samba version:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.50/backup /mnt/Backup -o username=usuario,password=contraseña,vers=x.0
```

This is the /etc/fstab content (no changes after and before failing):

```
//192.168.1.50/backup /mnt/Backup cifs x-systemd.automount,_netdev,credentials=/etc/samba/samba-credential.conf,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
```

The samba credential file still exists and have 0600 permission.

When I do a mount -a it gets this error:

```
sudo mount -a
mount error(95): Operation not supported
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)
```

And the dmesg get this all times the same code:

```
[ 1292.567834] CIFS: Attempting to mount //192.168.1.50/backup
[ 1292.640457] CIFS: VFS: parse_reparse_point: unhandled reparse tag: 0x9000e01a
[ 1292.640484] CIFS: VFS: cifs_read_super: get root inode failed
```

The samba version its still the same than before upgrading:

```
$ smbclient --version
Version 4.17.8-Raspbian
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Hi everyone.

I discovered that reparse tag: 0x9000e01a references something like a onedrive files property. In this CIFS kernel update (I suppose) it seems that couldnt load onedrive files, but if I mount a shared file out of onedrive it works.

For me its still a problem because I have more machines using the onedrive route and it would force me to reconfigure all my servers. Also I think this is a bug I can report.

In other servers original route still works.

Please the person who disliked this question can go and suck a dick and stop reading stack overflow if he cant answer it.